# right: 0 won't work with absolute positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a site using Bootstrap 3.3.6

I've followed a tutorial on creating a responsive banner slider like this: http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Full-Width-Responsive-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html

I'd like to have options to position the text (which is inside `.carousel-caption`) on either the right or left of the banner, occupying 50% of the available width.

The markup I have for the first slide is like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('foo.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Hello World</h3>                
            <p>Some more text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Positioning it to the right won't work using the following CSS (it remains on the left). It's as though `right: 0;` isn't being obeyed, even though `.carousel-caption` is positioned absolutely using Bootstrap.

```
.carousel-caption {  
   max-width: 500px;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: auto;    
}
```

I also realise that setting the `max-width` to 500px isn't really ideal, but when I tried 50% it seems to inherit the width of the whole browser window?

Comment: You can just use `text-align: right;` right?

Comment: You can use position absolute in carousel-caption class

Comment: but you haven't added `position:absolute` and `width:50%` (unless those styles are inherited from bootstrap)?

Comment: @Pete when I inspect it using Chrome Dev Tools it's already saying .carousel-caption is positioned absolutely (Bootstrap is doing this via carousel.less). in any case I've tried explicitly setting that in my own CSS and it made no difference.

Comment: Can you please add JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ah ok, I see, by default the caption has `right:20% left: 20%`, so only changing the right to 0 will only move the right further right, you need to change left to 50% (if you only want it to be half width) so add `left:50%` to your caption class override

Comment: @Pete `left:50%` seems to have worked. Although it only looks correct because of the `max-width: 500px` rule, which won't be good for a responsive layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the caption has `right:20%; left: 20%`, so only changing the right to 0 will only move the right further right.  You need to change left to 50% (if you only want it to be half width):

```css
.carousel-caption {
  max-width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

Although, now I noticed you have a max width so not sure if this would start from the left or right.  To solve this, you need to cancel the left and add a width of 50%:

```css
.carousel-caption {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

This should make it right aligned and 50% width up to a max width of 500px, but always placed on the right

Comment: I've accepted this answer. It's hard to explain this without a jsfiddle (I tried setting that up it wouldn't run). But on the tutorial if you implement left/right scroll arrows (inside `.carousel-control`), I really wanted the text *inside* the left/right of these. The last CSS solution pushes the text up to the absolute right of the browser window. It's kind of like the difference between `.container` and `.container-fluid` in Bootstrap. Ideally I want the text on the right of `.container`. The first of the CSS rules does pretty much what I want, although not when it goes down to mobile res.

Comment: try using bootply instead of fiddle (more geared towards bootstrap sites)