# sticky position a button to top right?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a button `position:sticky` stick to the top right at all times?

I tried:

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
}

input {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}

article{
  width:200%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="button" value="copy" />

  <article>
    In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.
  </article>
  
</div>
```

This works perfectly vertically but not horizontally

**Note:**
The width and height of the parent div can vary, it is set to `20rem` only for this example

Comment: why an item would have a width equal to 200%? Doesn't make a lot of sense to create an overflow like that. I suggest you share you real use case with a real code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that `200%` was just an example don't mind that, my main goal is to stick a button (or any element) to the top right of the container regardless of what the container width or it's content's width is

Answer (score 1):

You can make the button stick to the top right at all times by adding left: 90% to the input as somewhat explained in this answer solving a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39226548/22822396

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
}

input {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left: 90%;
}

article{
  width:200%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="button" value="copy" />

  <article>
    In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.
  </article>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This does [sort of work](https://jsfiddle.net/uy4dh2r8/11/) with `calc()` but I have to eyeball it with the `3rem` which would be a problem if the text in the button varies, so is there a way to get it to be exactly the width of the button (or whatever is sticking to the top right)?

Comment: @M.R.M. are you planning to use only `HTML` and `CSS` or `javascript`/`jquery` solution would also work?

Comment: I did consider using calc(), but to be honest I'm not entirely sure how I would approach it

Comment: @mandy8055 purely HTML & CSS

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found was to add another div as such:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3rem;
  right: 1rem; /* 1rem to avoid scrollbar width*/
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

article {
  width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <input type="button" value="copy" />

  <div class="content">

    <article>
      In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.
    </article>

  </div>

</div>
```

It's similar to [Dalton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77383774/22302305) except it works regardless of the text length inside the button
*i.e.* you don't have to guess the width of the button only the scrollbar

I'm still open to a pure css solution if anyone has one

Comment: you can replace `left: calc(100% - 1rem);transform: translate(-100%, 0)` with `right: 1rem`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know how I missed that, thank you! would u happen to know how to include the thickness of the scrollbar so I don't have to guess `1rem` for `right` of the button ( since I'm guessing different browsers have different scrollbar widths)?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do `position:fixed;` in css property

Comment: I want it to be sticky only to the container not to the entire page :)